# Spring boot Kafka Streams how can I trigger then stop a windowed aggregation processor when a certain message is detected

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KafkaStreams Processor that I trigger via http post like this:

```
      Properties props = new Properties();
      StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
      KStream<String, String> stream = builder.stream("input-topic");
      
      stream.transform((k, v) -> new Wrapper().setName(v.getName()).setId(v.getId())
            .groupBy((k, v) -> v.getId())
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(30)));
            .aggregate()
            .toStream().to('output-topic')

      
      Topology topology = builder.build(kafkaProps);

      final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);

      streams.start();
```

**How can detect when a message that comes in meets a certain condition, then stop the input stream from consuming messages, but still let the 30 minute aggregation window run its course? Any ideas?**

Comment: Have you tried using a [`filter`](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/filter-a-stream-of-events/kstreams.html)? You could check for a condition and have it evaluate as `false` past the message that you wish to check against. 

I'm not quite sure what the behaviour is with regards to windowing when no new message come in though. I believe that the window is closed only once a new message comes whose time - event or stream time, depending on your config, is past the window, keeping in mind retention time. Check the docs to make sure and make sure to verify with a test.